# Test-First Learn_Ruby 00_hello Rake aborted

Tags: ruby, rake

Your help would be MUCH appreciated. I am new to programming and want am trying to start alexch's Learn_Ruby, but am stuck on the very first lesson: 00_hello.
I am running "rake" test am am getting weird errors:

```
Justins-MacBook-Pro:00_hello Justin$ rake
(in /Users/Justin/Desktop/learn_ruby-master)
rake aborted!
undefined method `gem' for main:Object
/Users/Justin/Desktop/learn_ruby-master/Rakefile:2
(See full trace by running task with --trace)
```

I'm just following the instructions from the course: https://github.com/alexch/learn_ruby/blob/master/index.html

here are my specs:
ruby 1.8.7
rspec 2.12
gem 1.8.25

anything thing else i'm missing??
Your Help is MUCH appreciate.

here is the gem list:

```
Justins-MacBook-Pro:00_hello Justin$ gem list

*** LOCAL GEMS ***

activemodel (3.2.11)
activerecord (3.2.11)
activesupport (3.2.11)
arel (3.0.2)
builder (3.1.4, 3.0.4)
diff-lcs (1.2.0, 1.1.3)
i18n (0.6.1)
multi_json (1.5.0)
rspec (2.12.0)
rspec-core (2.12.2)
rspec-expectations (2.12.1)  
rspec-mocks (2.12.2)
rubygems-update (1.8.25)
tzinfo (0.3.35)
uuidtools (2.1.3)
```

Comment: this is the error i'm expecting....according to the manual:  1) the hello function says hello
   Failure/Error: hello().should == "Hello!"
     expected: "Hello!"
          got: "whuh?" (using ==)
   # ./hello/hello_spec.rb:5:in `block (2 levels) in <top (required)>'

Comment: Please run `gem list` command from the `00_hello` folder, and include the output in the question; it will help in figuring out the problem.

Comment: i've added the gem list from 00_hello folder. thanks

Comment: What's the output from running `which rake`?

Comment: You might want to run `bundle install` in the folder

Answer (score 0):

First update rubygems by following command:

```
gem update --system
```

That should solve it.

If not then try removing the following line from the rakefile

```
gem 'rspec', '~>2'
```